# Firebase app distribution url returns 404 error

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-app-distribution

I have recently finished developing an application and I wanted to publish it between few friends to test it.

I have sent it to 4 different users where 3 opened it without any problem while the 4th user receives the following error:

[image]

Is there any reason why it happens or how I can fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Hey Ben, any news? I'm also facing the same issue

Comment: @Royz nope, sent request and waiting for an answer. Will let you know.

Comment: still nothing ?

Comment: From your names I think we are all from the same country, maybe it is connected somehow. But still waiting. Sent them links and stuff.

Comment: Their support sent me to Slack to ask there. Didnt forget you, will update here =)

Comment: @Royz Hey all, check my answer for more details, but long story short, we weren't handling the iw locale properly. The app should now load for everyone!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anthony from the App Distribution team here. We have found the root cause and pushed out a fix yesterday.

It turned out that we were not handling the `iw` locale properly (which is an old, deprecated version of `he` that some devices still send). Now, we properly load the page and show Hebrew for that specific ISO 639-1 code.

Testers should now be able to use the site without issue. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Thanks for the help =)

Comment: @Anthony Oh, great to see the developers answering SO questions :D, so it was a problem specific to Hebrew? Did my answer helped you to find the root cause? In any case upvoted you answer and thanks a lot!

Comment: @MaxLipnitsky :) And yes, it was specific to the `iw` locale, pretty wild. `he` always worked fine, however. It's funny, I think we missed that bit in your answer before, but I was telling the team that it would probably have led us in the right direction earlier! Thanks so much for that!

Comment: This problem just returns to happen today.

Comment: Yes, facing the same issue again.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, I finally managed to narrow down the issue to the browser type which is launched once clicking on the invite link. On Samsung devices, the default browser is "samsung interent" which couldn't handle properly(not sure why) the invite link, once setting the default browser to chrome everything worked as expected.

Comment: Thats interesting, I will test it. Thank you.

Comment: Did it work for you? because it doesn't  for me, @Ben

Comment: @honey, try to take the resulting url and paste it manually in chrome. Also try to reinvite(delete->add) the tester from the dashboard. Those are all rhe steps i did, which eventually worked.

Comment: Hey all, check my answer for more details, but long story short, we weren't handling the `iw` locale properly, which I believe was why Chrome worked and Samsung Internet didn't (Samsung Internet might still use that deprecated locale code, but Chrome doesn't). All browsers and devices should work now :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just managed to solve this issue on Galaxy Note 10.. had no problem on Galaxy S9.

Solution:
1 - Following the answer from Evgeni Roitburg I've copied the actual link from the "accept" button, using the "share" function and sending it to myself.. and opened it manually in Google Chrome, but it still gave me "404"..

2 - Out of instinct I've tried to change the phone language to English, it was in Hebrew.. After that the link started to work when opened in Chrome.

Need to mention that I've also made sure that the "user" on this phone's GooglePlay is the same gmail user which was invited via Firebase.

It seems that there is no mentions of this issue in the internet after searching Google a little.. Hope this solution will help you.

Comment: Hey Max, check my answer for more details, but long story short, we weren't handling the iw locale properly. The app should now load on all device/browser combos now :)